# How to test the value of an argument using Mocha and assert.throws in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, assert

I want to see if a value that equals 'x' will cause my function to throw an exception. I have a unit test that checks if a block will throw an exception, but I want the exception to be thrown only if the argument = 'x', not if its just empty. How do I do this using assert?

Here's some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
// Some function to check if a color is not transparent.
function checkColor(color) {
  if (color == 'transparent') {
    throw new TypeError('cant have transparent colors!');
  } else {
    return color;
  }
}
```

Here's the assert:

```
assert.throws(checkColor, /cant have transparent colors!/);
```

Now, I know that assertion will fail because my function only throws the exception if the color == 'transparent'.  Using Mocha and Assert, how do I test the assertion as I want it?  I don't want to merely test if color !== undefined or is of some type.  I specifically want to see if the exception is raised under the specific circumstance above - which is the only circumstance I want the exception to be raised (since having an empty color, is actually handled elsewhere).

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Include code to demonstrate your requirements

Comment: "a value that equals 'x' will throw an exception" Values don't throw exceptions, functions do. "but I want the exception to be thrown only if the argument = 'x'" then tell your function to throw an exception when the argument is `'x'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
assert.throw(function() { iThrowError(argument) }, Error)
```

Now just make sure argument = x;

Comment: Ugh... I'm an idiot! I saw this very example hours earlier and totally spaced out on that. I'll give this is shot, I'm sure it will work.